# Proof that $A + 1 \leq e^A$ for all $A > 0$

Tags: proof-writing

I was reading a proof where at a certain point the prover uses the following inequality

$$A + 1 \leq e^A$$

which in my opinion needs also a proof to be used around. I think I'm missing some important fundamental property which is well-known, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Consider the function $f(A)=e^A-A-1$ and find its minimum by differentiation.

Comment: This is clear geometrically: the function $e^x$ has tangent line $y = x+1$ at $x = 0$ and it lies everywhere above any tangent line (look at the graphs, or use the second derivative test), so $e^x \geq x+1$ for all $x$, in fact with equality only for $x = 0$.

Comment: Why are the answerers only doing the case of $A>0$?

Comment: @GEdgar, because that's what the OP asks for?  (Note, my answer addresses the general case in a remark at the end.)

Comment: @BarryCipra ...  OK, in the title, but not the text itself ...

Comment: @GEdgar, also, all the answers need a little extra reasoning to handle the case $A\lt0$.

Answer (score 4):

In the simple case of $A>0$, it suffices to just look at the taylor series definition:

$$1+A\leq 1+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\cdots=e^A$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$(e^x)' = e^x$
for all $x$,
and
$e^x > 1$
for
$x > 0$,
we have,
for $x > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
e^x-1
&=\int_0^x e^t dt\\
&> \int_0^x 1 dt
\qquad\text{since } e^x > 1 \text{ for } x > 0\\
&=x\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\gt-1$, we have

$$(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$$

which is easily proved by induction on $n$:

$$\begin{align}
(1+x)^n\ge1+nx\implies(1+x)^{n+1}&=(1+x)(1+x)^n\\
&\ge(1+x)(1+nx)\\
&=1+(n+1)x+nx^2\\
&\ge1+(n+1)x
\end{align}$$

It follows that, if $A\gt0$, then

$$\left(1+{A\over n}\right)^n\ge1+n\left(A\over n\right)=1+A$$

and thus

$$e^A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{A\over n}\right)^n\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+A)=1+A$$

Remark:  The inequality actually holds for *all* $A$, not just $A\gt0$, by the same proof, with the only extra wrinkle being that one needs to note that $A/n\gt-1$ for all $n\gt|A|$.

Comment: Of course, the proof of the limit for $e^A$ is the non-trivial part.

Comment: @martycohen, agreed.  But isn't the same true in your proof for the step $(e^x)'=e^x$?

Answer (score 0):

$A+1=e^A$ at $A=0$.

$\frac{d(A+1)}{dA}=1$, while $\frac{d(e^A)}{dA}=e^A$.

$e^A>1 \forall A>0$.

So they start off equivalent, but the RHS grows faster at all points than the LHS.